# How to install a specific emulator from command line with avdmanager?

Tags: android, android-emulator

As pointed in [How to create Android Virtual Device with command line and avdmanager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792947/how-to-create-android-virtual-device-with-command-line-and-avdmanager)
one can in principle create AVD from command line. Though it is not straightforward. Following the docs, there should be an option `-t` that specifies what particular device to emulate by specifying `targetId`.

Unfortunately, as of version 25.3.1 `avdmanager` does not recognize option `-t`.
There is an option `--tag` but it does not seem to be a `-t` equivalent, since it does not recognise the provided `targetId` (taken from the list).

How can I specify what device to emulate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Android Virtual Device with command line and avdmanager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792947/how-to-create-android-virtual-device-with-command-line-and-avdmanager)

Answer (score 10):

For e.g. `echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name x86 --device "4in WVGA (Nexus S)" --package "system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86" --tag "google_apis" --abi "x86"`

Where:

```
Usage:
      avdmanager [global options] create avd [action options]
      Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

Action "create avd":
  Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -a --snapshot: Place a snapshots file in the AVD, to enable persistence.
  -c --sdcard  : Path to a shared SD card image, or size of a new sdcard for
                 the new AVD.
  -g --tag     : The sys-img tag to use for the AVD. The default is to
                 auto-select if the platform has only one tag for its system
                 images.
  -p --path    : Directory where the new AVD will be created.
  -k --package : Package path of the system image for this AVD (e.g.
                 'system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86'). [required]
  -n --name    : Name of the new AVD. [required]
  -f --force   : Forces creation (overwrites an existing AVD)
  -b --abi     : The ABI to use for the AVD. The default is to auto-select the
                 ABI if the platform has only one ABI for its system images.
  -d --device  : The optional device definition to use. Can be a device index
                 or id.
```

Comment: `--tag "google_apis"` what does it mean? I want to emulate a device, as for example, a phone Nexus 4 or a tablet Nexus 10. They look ways differently. They should have different associated tags. But how do I know these tags?

Comment: tag can be `default|google_apis|android-tv|android-wear` depending on the image which you have downloaded. See list of possible images to download here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42521077/624706

List of possible device params: `avdmanager list device`

Comment: `avdmanager list device` gives you ids, but `--device` is not a meaningful parameter. image is a system, which can be installed on different devices.

Answer (score 8):

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
yes | ./sdkmanager emulator
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}"
./sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses
./avdmanager list device
./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools
sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
kvm-ok
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
./emulator -avd test
```

Answer (score 5):

The avdmanager tool and sdkmanager are provided in the Android SDK Tools package (25.3.0 and higher) and is located in {your_android_sdk_directory}/tools/bin/ 
in terminal run following commands:

1. ./sdkmanager list
2. ./avdmanager list device
3. ./avdmanager create avd -n pixel -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64" -d "17"

pixel is the name i gave to the avd.

"system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64" got from ./sdkmanager list in Installed packages

"17" is device id got from ./avdmanager list device

change directory to:

- cd {your_android_sdk_directory}/emulator

To open emulator run command:

- ./emulator -avd pixel

Pixel is the name given previously to the avd.

Hope it helps others with the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Android Emulator using the new [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) command line tool and create AVDs via the new [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) command line tool. It is easier to do these tasks with the Android Studio [AVD manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: For example per the sdkmanger page ( https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html ), once you have the command line sdk tools installed (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) , you just type in the following to download the Android Emulator: $ ./sdkmanager "emulator"

Comment: @JamalEason in my case `emulator` appeared here - `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397/tools/emulator`, too sad that it's not under $PATH