# Exception during AvdManager initialization : expected a non-null reference

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

When I run the following command :

> c:\SDKs\android\cmdline-tools\8.0\bin\avdmanager.bat -v create avd -n
> android13 -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a"

I receive the error :

```
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Error: Exception during AvdManager initialization
Error: null
expected a non-null reference
```

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio on Windows now defaults to PowerShell:

```
cd .\cmdline-tools\latest\bin
.\sdkmanager.bat --list
.\avdmanager.bat -v create avd -n android13 -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a"
```

Directory `cmdline-tools\latest\bin` could also be added to PATH.

Or to install: `cmdline-tools;latest`

Comment: it's glorious! how did you know that cmdline-tools\latest\bin must be in the path ? anyway thanks !

Answer (score 1):

*Complete Re-edit* -- This answer is based on the Android Dev Docs on how to [start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline), the [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager) and the [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager), and now also considering an old Readme file of mine, this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792947/how-to-create-android-virtual-device-with-command-line-and-avdmanager#42798993) and this [guide](https://gist.github.com/mrk-han/66ac1a724456cadf1c93f4218c6060ae).

Used the paths as in your question, adapt at need.

---

**(1)** -- Download and install an image for Android 13 (API Level 33) on arm64-v8a ABI with the command:

```
c:\SDKs\android\cmdline-tools\8.0\bin\sdkmanager.bat --install "system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a"
```

If you're not sure which image to use, check for a list of installable images with:

```
c:\SDKs\android\cmdline-tools\8.0\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list | findstr "system-images"
```

**(2)** -- Create the AVD with

```
echo "no" | c:\SDKs\android\cmdline-tools\8.0\bin\avdmanager.bat create avd -f -n "android13" -b "arm64-v8a" -g "google_apis" -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a"
```

with `-f|--force` to enforce the creation (esp. to overwrite an existing one of same name), `-n|--name` for the AVD's name, `-b|--abi` to specify the target ABI, `-g|--tag` to specify the sytem image's tag, and `-k|--package` to provide the system image's path.

Using all this options avoids auto-select choices and such reduces the probability of corresponding failures.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help, I already did all of this :(

Comment: Hm. Is `"system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a"` in your `sdkmanager --list` at all? And if yes, are there for the configuration `"system-images;android-33;X;arm64-v8a"` other variants than **X** =`google_apis`?

Comment: yes system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a is in my sdkmanager --list and only system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a :  system-images;android-33;google_apis;arm64-v8a | 6            | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image | system-images\android-33\google_apis\arm64-v8a

Comment: Completely re-edited the answer and deleted my last 3 comments as obsolete.

Comment: thanks Krokomot for your help! the problem was that i missed cmdline-tools\latest\bin in the path :(

Comment: Alright, good to know for myself.